# JAVA - Global Number Rounding

Tags: java, rounding

Some languages (PHP, ASP, etc.) let you set environmental/locale variables for currencies, rounding, etc. Does JAVA have something like this? Something so that all floats or anything wild is rounded to maybe 2 or 3 decimal places? I know of DecimalFormat and setRoundingMode, but can't find any answers or anything in the API.

Clarity: rather than having to DecimalFormat every single number you use or output, is there a way to set JAVA's internal rounding (to automatically be 2 or 3 decimal places) or the way it handles floats?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Please provide more details for what you are up to.

Comment: your questions needs more clarity

Comment: *Nothing* changes the way it handles (doubles and) floats except the presence of `strictfp`. Don't mix that up with formatting or conversion to `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that what you are trying is not doable. Even setting the default locale will not help here. You want a way to set the formatting globally, but the bottom line is that you will have to *invoke* some kind of formatting (e.g. use a `NumberFormat` implementation).

What you *can* do is create a globally accessible static function that you will use everywhere you need to. Not the greatest approach, but *whatever works* (as Woody Allen says).

Comment: Easy enough. I didn't think there was, just am not a JAVA expert like you guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use BigDecimal for currencies. It is fixed digit rounding capable. Never use floating point numbers for currencies they are inaccurate.
You can setup MathContext for rounding there.